# Using a singular to convey a plural

Tags: grammar, nouns, usage

If I want to provide a diagram of the performance measurements of different programming languages, which option is correct? Is it correct to use a singular form when there are multiple languages taken into account?

- "Programming languages performance"
- "Programming language performance"

Similar:

- The package groups elements according to the elements type.
- The package groups elements according to the element type.

I feel like in English it is possible to use a singular when in fact you are indicating a plurality, does anyone know of any specific rules regarding this?

Thank you.

Comment: If the first is the title of the diagram, either will do. In the second, "The package groups elements according to *their* type."

Comment: There ought to be apostrophes in the first versions: "Programming language's performance", "The package groups elements according to the element's type". The first phrase in particular could be ambiguously interpreted as [The action of] programming language performance.

Comment: If you're making noun compounds, all nouns preceding the head noun should be singular. No matter what they mean. So it's a _Shoe Store_ even though one buys more than one shoe there.

Comment: (1) I'd say the advice to use genitives (apostrophised forms) here would be considered reliable by very few practiced Anglophones nowadays. Use attributives. // (2) Though the default form of a noun used attributively is the singular, there is no cast-in-stone rule about this. With novel strings, it's often advisable, but can be overridden, especially when one wishes to make it clear that more than one language say is being addressed. There are 16 000 Google hits for "languages performance", and "Modern Languages Performance" seems idiomatic.

Comment: @JohnLawler We do have "clothes shops" though, even though we can buy a single garment rather than shoes which we buy in  pairs. Having said that I'll give you "garment shops" and "clothing shops".

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I think in the two examples provided either would be fine.

Comment: @Casey I refer to three alternatives. // The use of the apostrophe in such cases is very rare in headlines, titles and the commercial and technical domains nowadays. This is covered elsewhere on ELU. For non-true-ownership, the apostrophe is disappearing. 155 hits on Google for "programming language's performance", most of them showing ownership (as with "the Alpha Programming language's performance"). Suffice it to say that 'working mens clubs' is now the favoured variant in the UK. A new word!